# tailwatchd - chkservd on host.domain.com status: hang

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

`The chkservd sub-process with pid 17420 was running for 602 seconds.  The sub-process was terminated as it exceeded the time between checks of 300 seconds.  Please check /var/log/chkservd.log and /usr/local/cpanel/logs/tailwatchd_log to discover the`

I was notified for this error by email on the destination server while transferring server. what does it mean ?

and also this happened:

```
ftpd failed @ Wed Aug  8 11:26:38 2012. A restart was attempted automagically.

Service Check Method:  [socket connect]

Reason: Timeout while trying to get data from service: Died at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/TailWatch/ChkServd.pm line 607.


Number of Restart Attempts: 1

    Startup Log: Starting pure-config.pl: Running: /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd -O clf:/var/log/xferlog --daemonize -A -c50 -B -C8 -D -fftp -H -I15 -lextauth:/var/run/ftpd.sock -L10000:8 -m4 -s -U133:022 -u100 -Oxferlog:/usr/local/apache/domlogs/ftpxferlog -k99 -Z -Y1 -JHIGH:MEDIUM:+TLSv1:!SSLv2:+SSLv3
    [  OK  ]
    Starting pure-authd:
```

Comment: What setup do you have: are these physical or virtual machines? How much memory, CPU? Do you have any relevant log snippets, and did you notice it was particularly slow (did you check IO/CPU/load averages)? Any data you can give will help answer the question.

Comment: Thanks, It's a virtual machine, KVM preallocated qcow2 Disk with virtio and also virtio NIC. 4GB of memory on 64bit CentOS 5.8 with 4 cores assigned. I think it because of apache and php, I changed to mpm_worker and mod_fcgid and it doesn't hang anymore but it's a little slow and that's the problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether server load was high when you received this alert. High server load can cause this issue. Check dcpumon

```
#/var/log/dcpumon/toplog
```

OR run

```
#sar -q
```

Check whether spam assassin is installed

```
#rpm -qa | grep -i spam
```

If spam assassin is installed uninstall spam assassin using

```
#rpm -e spamassassin
```

reinstall spamassassin:

```
#/scripts/installspam
/scripts/fixspamassassinfailedupdate
```

run

```
#/scripts/upcp --force
```